# C++ compilation error: reference to constructor is ambiguous

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a single source file C++ program I'm trying to compile.

The header file looks like:

```
class merge {
public:
explicit merge(int argc, char* argv[]);
virtual ~merge();
};
```

And the source file looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
merge mrg(argc,argv);
return 0;
}

merge::merge(map<string,string>& params) {
    //code
}
```

Trying to compile with:
g++ merge.cpp -o merge

I get:

```
 merge.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    merge.cpp:10: error: reference to ‘merge’ is ambiguous
    merge.h:12: error: candidates are: class merge
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-            linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:3180: error: template<class     _InputIterator1, class _InputIterator2, class _OutputIterator, class _Compare>     _OutputIterator std::merge(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2,     _InputIterator2, _OutputIterator, _Compare)
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:3122: error: template<class     _InputIterator1, class _InputIterator2, class _OutputIterator> _OutputIterator     std::merge(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _InputIterator2,     _OutputIterator)
    merge.cpp:10: error: reference to ‘merge’ is ambiguous
    merge.h:12: error: candidates are: class merge
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:3180: error: template<class     _InputIterator1, class _InputIterator2, class _OutputIterator, class _Compare>     _OutputIterator std::merge(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2,     _InputIterator2, _OutputIterator, _Compare)
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:3122: error: template<class     _InputIterator1, class _InputIterator2, class _OutputIterator> _OutputIterator     std::merge(_InputIterator1, _InputIterator1, _InputIterator2, _InputIterator2,     _OutputIterator)
    merge.cpp:10: error: expected `;' before ‘mrg’
    merge.cpp: At global scope:
    merge.cpp:14: error: prototype for ‘merge::merge(std::map<std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)’ does not     match any in class ‘merge’
    merge.h:12: error: candidates are: merge::merge(const merge&)
    merge.h:14: error:                 merge::merge(int, char**)
    merge.cpp: In constructor ‘merge::merge(std::map<std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)’:
    merge.cpp:15: error: declaration of ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,     std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > params’     shadows a parameter
    merge.cpp:16: error: ‘argc’ was not declared in this scope
    merge.cpp:16: error: ‘argv’ was not declared in this scope
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: At global scope:
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation     of ‘std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> > >’:
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:803:   instantiated from ‘void     std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_InputIterator, _InputIterator,     __false_type) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:262:   instantiated from     ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Alloc&) [with     _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,     _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’
    merge.cpp:86:   instantiated from here
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:129: error: no     type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,     std::allocator<char> >’
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Apparently, you included some standard library headers in your code, and there is a `std::merge` function which confuses the name lookup.  Maybe you included `using namespace std;` too?  Since we can't see the exact source you're compiling (there isn't a line 10 in the code you show!), we can't easily guess — and we shouldn't have to guess.

Answer (score 4):

In the class declaration you have

```
explicit merge(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

But when you provide a definition for the constructor you have

```
merge::merge(map<string,string>& params) { /* ... */ }
```

Of course, the two must match.

Also, it seems you have a `using namespace std;` statement in your code somewhere. The compiler cannot resolve whether the calls to `merge` are to your `merge` class constructor or to [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

The lesson to take away from this (other than fix your constructor):

> **DO NOT** add `using namespace std;` *anywhere* in your code. `std::` is not very cumbersome to type.

Comment: Second "DO NOT `add using namespace std;` anywhere in your code". Want to add that, at least in my opinion, having `std::` usually makes the code much more clear about things.

Comment: @BeyondSora may be work for you that now `std` well, but if someone is not familiar with `std` and declare a class and function that have same name as `std` class or function then it will get some strange errors like this one, and beside that if you want to compile your code by a future version of `std` you can't do that since `std` may add a class or function with same name as yours and your code will fail to compile. So if you feel uneasy with `std::` just use those parts that you need, for example `using std::cout`

Comment: @user1701545 AFAIK in C++ `explicit` apply to constructors that only take one argument to avoid implicit conversion so constructors that take more than one argument(like `merge` constructor) never need to be `explicit` because the can't be implicit!

Answer (score 3):

The signature of merge's constructor does not match its definition.

In your class declaration, you defined `merge::merge` to take in two parameters, one `int` and the other `char*`. In the definition for `merge::merge`, however, you define it as taking in only one parameter of type `map<string,string>&`